# Facebook Android SDK Call facebook.authorize when a Facebook request fails

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to call facebook.authorize whenever a request made by my app to facebook fails.

But it throws a `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() inside`   listener error.

I am making the call from a try-catch on Facebook error handler.

Is there another way of handling this?

Comment: You should probably post your code to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: ah ok, will upload once i get home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved over here

[Facebook authorize not working inside Android Asynctask or Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338470/facebook-authorize-not-working-inside-android-asynctask-or-thread)

```
            Looper.prepare();
            facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
            Looper.loop();
```