# Can't create two looper in the same activity while executing 2 facebook functions - Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

First I want to sign in with Facebook. For that I used Android Facebook SDK.
Code for that

```
            facebook.authorize(ac, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
```

It didn't work. So I need to put Looper.prepare() and Looper.loop().

```
            Looper.prepare();
            facebook.authorize(ac, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
            Looper.loop();
```

After Logged in, with another button click I want to give a post to a friend's wall. So I used

```
        Looper.prepare();
    AsyncFacebookRunner as=new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    as.request(userId+"/feed", paramss, "POST",  new WallPostRequestListener(), null);
   Looper.loop();
```

This is showing error, saying that

> Only one looper may be created per thread

If I use the code without the looper lines, like

```
    AsyncFacebookRunner as=new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    as.request(userId+"/feed", paramss, "POST",  new WallPostRequestListener(), null);
```

Then it shows error, saying

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I've searched net for solution , can't find any. I need to use both functions on the same Activity. So please help if any one knows what's wrong with my code........ And consider me as begginer in Android with very little knowledge of thread........

Comment: Can you post all your code?  In most normal cases, you never have to call `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()`

Comment: Total code is of 445 lines..!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338470/facebook-authorize-not-working-inside-android-asynctask-or-thread
From this link you can get the main part. This is why I needed to use looper.loop();

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do the authentication inside an `AsyncTask`?  `facebook.authorize()` is already asynchronous, that is why you are having this problem.

Comment: okay, adjusted code without the AsyncTask, it worked. Also tried thread while posting, that worked too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {


                AsyncFacebookRunner as=new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
                as.request(userId+"/feed", paramss, "POST",  new WallPostRequestListener(), null);

        }
```

This is a solution of my problem. Or another way would be as mentioned in comments by Jesse Chen